# Submitting data using ngrx effects or a component

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

We had a discussion here with a friend of mine related to a task where "what should happen if one clicks the submit button of a form"?
The requirement is to first validate that form using data in the ngrx store and then submit that data to a server.

...so there are 2 ways of doing that:

- using the ngrx/effects which will be fired when an "SUBMIT_ACTION" is being dispatched. It will get the data and then call the API through service
- using the component - it will "take(1)" the configuration, validate that everything is fine and then call the API through service

As I know - it is a commonn thing to use effects is such situations. What do you think?

Comment: Don't think the place for that logic should be in the component. Normally I would place that in a service that would be called from an effect. In the effect you can also fetch whatever data you need from the state (probably with something like withLatestFrom).

Comment: They even do this in the [official example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no right answer for this question.
Personally i don´t like to push the validation into the store. I prefer to validate my forms with the in-build validations tools from angular.
For my current project we are using reactive forms to validate the input and then keep those forms in sync with the store.
(Additional we are syncing attributes like valid, touched, pending, error)

One advantages is that you are able to submit forms from basically everywhere or split them into smaller pieces and merge them before sending them to the server.
And you are able to write reusable angular components which are agnostic to the underlying store architecture and can be easily refactored. To bind the forms to the store you could use a service or an abstract class.

Short example:

- Reactive form validates input
- form data gets synced with store (including if it is valid, pending, error)
- UI elements (submit button/form disabled/spinner) are linked to the valid/pending attribute
- a "SUBMIT_ACTION" is dispatched and changes the state to pending=true
- effect is waiting for an answer and dispatches "SUBMIT_ACTION_ERROR" or "SUBMIT_ACTION_SUCCESS"
- display error or shows success notification

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no right answer to this question, it all depends and it's your job as a developer to pick the right solution.

Personally if it's a simple form, I would do:

- validate if the form is filled in correctly (client-side validation)
- dispatch a save action with the (serializable) form object, this isn't the form of Angular but just a JavaScript object
- listen for this action in an effect and call the service
- if something went wrong: show a message (notification, toaster, snackbar, …)
- if everything is OK: close the form